# Java threads get terminated instantly

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to do some parallel http calls and database writing using threads in Java. The roblem is that after calling thread.start() the thread does not call the run method but goes into TERMINATED state instantly.

```
while (fromIndex < list.size()) {
                final int toIndex = fromIndex + batchSize > list.size() ? list.size() : fromIndex + batchSize;
                fromIndex += batchSize;
                final int fromIndexCopy = fromIndex;
                threads[i] = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        processConsumptionHistory(requestContext, list.subList(fromIndexCopy, toIndex), listFinished,
                                listFailed, listEnd);
                        markFailedUsage(listFailed);
                    }
                };
                threads[i].start();
                i++;
            }

            for (final Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
```

Why do threads not run? Is there a better alternative?

**EDIT**

Threads do get started, the problem is that the lists passed are empty.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, see [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: We know nothing about your lists and your `process…` method. So how can we help? Except to say, as Covaci commented, you should be using the Executors framework that was added to Java so that we app programmers would be freed from manually managing threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to reverse the order of these two statements:

```
fromIndex += batchSize;
final int fromIndexCopy = fromIndex;
```

Comment: Yes, lists I was processing was empty. Great observation!